# vertical align to bottom for inline-block element not working

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I have been trying to make the button vertically aligned to bottom, and I think I can easily do it using `display:inline-block` method, but not sure what I am doing wrong here!

```css
.cons_wrap_right {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 175px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 25%;
  background:#cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="cons_wrap_right">
    <button type="submit" class="ask_btn">Ask Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to understand that `vertical-align` does not refer to the containing element, but to the *line of text*  that the element is part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a pseudo element before `button`.

**EDIT: Why use pseudo element**

You need it to stretch the content to full width. See the `vertical-align` does not work with respect to the parent height but is with respect to the height the content is taking.

Initially when you only have a button content height is only equal to the button height but by using pseudo element, the content stretches to full height.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8d28mt1/3/) to explain it. In this fiddle see the button being aligned at the bottom of the content.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.cons_wrap_right {
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 25%;
  height:50%;
  background:#cccccc;
}
.cons_wrap_right .pseudo{
  display: inline-block;
  width:1px;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  background:#cccccc;
}
.cons_wrap_right button{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="cons_wrap_right">
  <div class="pseudo"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="ask_btn">Ask Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am wondering why should I add pseudo, please explain

Comment: you need it to stretch the content to full width. see the `vertical-align` is not with respect to the parent height but is with respect to the height the content is taking. Initially when you only have a button content height is only equal to the button height but by using pseudo element, the content stretches to full height

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `table` and `table-cell`

```css
.cons_wrap_right {
  display: table;
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.innerBox {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="cons_wrap_right">
  <div class="innerBox">
    <button type="submit" class="ask_btn">Ask Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with `table` layouts, you should use `height` instead of `min-height`, because tables have fluid layout by default, so `min-height` won't work and `height` will behave like a `min-height` with `display: table`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this are using `position` or `flex`. See snippets below for examples.

```css
/* using position relative and absolute */

.cons_wrap_right {
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.ask_btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* using flexbox */

.cons_wrap_right2 {
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="cons_wrap_right">
  <button type="submit" class="ask_btn">Ask Now</button>
</div>
<div class="cons_wrap_right2">
  <button type="submit" class="ask_btn2">Ask Now</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the container `position: relative` and the button `position: absolute` plus `bottom: 0`:

```css
.cons_wrap_right {
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #cccccc;
  position: relative;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cons_wrap_right">
  <button type="submit" class="ask_btn">Ask Now</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting position absolute for button class.Like--

```css
.cons_wrap_right {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 175px;
  position:relative;
  width: 25%;
  background:#cccccc;
}
.ask_btn{
  position: absolute;
  left:    0;
  bottom:   0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cons_wrap_right">
    <button type="submit" class="ask_btn">Ask Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but is it possible to move button without using position:absolute?

Comment: obviously,you can see that from the other answer too.It's possible.I like to do this in this way.